# Writing a function to call other functions without calling on the user prompts

Tags: javascript, function, dom, prompt

I'm trying to write a function that calls others function to produce a final answer. However, if I try to call halfNumber and squarenumber functions, I'm also going to be calling the individual prompts from those functions, and I don't want that to happen. Is there a way I can restructure my code so, I can be able to call crazyFunction without calling the prompts from the other functions?

Javascript:

```
var el1 = document.getElementById('squarenum');
el1.onclick = squarenumber;

var el2 = document.getElementById('halfnum');
el2.onclick = halfNumber;

function squarenumber(n){

    n = prompt("Enter a number to be squared");
    var result = n * n;


    var txt = document.getElementById('square_answer');
    txt.innerHTML = "The result of squaring the number " + n + " is " + result; 
    return result;
}

function halfNumber(num){

    num = prompt("Enter a number to be halved");
    var result = num/2;
    var txt = document.getElementById('halved_answer');
    txt.innerHTML = "Half of " + num + " is " + result;
    return result;

}

function crazyFunction(num){
    result1 = squarenumber(num);
    result2 = halfNumber(result1);

    return result2;
}
```

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li><a href="#" id="squarenum">squarenumber</a></li>

    <p id='square_answer'>The square is...</p>
    <li><a href="#" id='halfnum'>halfNumber</a></li>
    <p id='halved_answer'>Half of the number is...</p>
    <li><a href="#" id='crazyfunction'>crazyfunction</a></li>
    <p id='crazy_answer'>This function is a surprise...</p>
</ol>
```

Comment: Would have to add additional parameter of bool to check if prompt should be called with structure you have.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve your issue. Firstly, try understand why you're creating these functions and understand the requirements.

The expected output is that when `squarenumber` or `halfNumber` are called individually, you want a prompt to show, otherwise if they are called from within `crazyFunction`, the desired output is to not show a prompt.

So, we can see that the fluctuation in control flow lies at the moment of the function being called. Therefore, it would make the most sense for you to come up with a solution to this problem based on the passed in arguments to the sub functions of `squarenumber` and `halfNumber`.

#### Basic Solution

```js
function crazyFunction(num) {
    boolean shouldShowPrompt = false;
    let result1 = squarenumber(num, shouldShowPrompt);
    let result2 = halfNumber(result1, shouldShowPrompt);

    return result2;
}
```

And then the `halfNumber` example:

```js
function halfNumber(num, shouldShowPrompt ) {

    if (shouldShowPrompt) {
        num = prompt("Enter a number to be halved");
    }

    var result = num / 2;
    var txt = document.getElementById('halved_answer');
    txt.innerHTML = "Half of " + num + " is " + result;
    return result;

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, but when I just call halfNumber, how do I get the prompt to run, since shouldShowPrompt is always false?

Comment: You can decide that in the crazyFuncrion, IE `squarenumber(num, true);` or `squarenumber(num, false);`. You have control over how it behaves from the outer function.